# Bulk insert failing with large number of duplicate values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

the error occurs:- when adding 1000000 number to the database with bulk insert
error- process stop with giving too man duplication value

finding: - as I think bulk insert happen with 1000 chunk.so if in 1000 chunk 800 duplicate all process stops without trying other 900000. But if duplicate value less than 100 the insert process happen smoothly

`mongo ---- MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
deployment — standalone`

I am using molecular js.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, are you trying to avoid duplicates?

Comment: you can check while uploading the data for duplicates. if duplicate then ignore that data.

Comment: @buddika bandana : I think it's not the issue with duplicates, are you doing this op with option `{ordered : false}` ? Do you want to insert duplicates (Do you've any unique key index )? Also bulkWrite can take upto 100k docs a chunk if you send more then it would internally chunk docs..

Comment: @whoami : yes them chunk 1000 and if duplicate keys there the all process false.yes i have use ordered:false and i have unique key for each row